# Powershell fails to install PowerShellGet because of Unable to download from URI

Tags: powershell, security, tls1.2

Recently I've started with a fresh W10 Pro image, hooked up to a domain. My user role is Local and Domain-admin. I tried to setup my powershell environment to install some powershell packages via PowershellGet starting first with `Install-Module PowershellGet -Force` but i always get the error `WARNING: Unable to download from URI 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=627338&clcid=0x409' to ''.`

So i starting googling and found out that this has to do with the fact that the PowershellGallaray site has disabled old security protocols. Meaning i have to set Powershell to use TLS1.2. Running the command `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12` should fix this but is does set the protocol to TLS1.2 but i still get the same error.

Then i did some more googling and saw on the [Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client) and also [this page](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/is-it-possible-to-enable-tls-1-2-as-default-in-powershell/) that i can set the default behaviour for security. Set this setting in registry restarted the computer and again still the same error. Also when i check the securityprotocol in Powershell it says SystemDefault.

Spend several hours more on google searching what can fix this but can't find a solution that works. Any tips or trics? (except installing W10 again...)

Powershell version = 5.1.19041.1
Windows version = W10 Pro 2004 build 19041.264

Answer (score 0):

After searching several hours i tried on a different internet connection and it did work! Turns out the network guys changed the firewall rules...